# Bootstrap 5 Navbar Dropdown Popper Not Working

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap 5.3 the latest release. I have the bootstrap javascript file downloaded into a js folder named bootstrap.js with the bootstrap code. I have popper downloaded and saved into the js folder named popper.js, The dropdown was working last night but when i started working it was giving me the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Popper__namespace.createPopper is not a function
    at Dropdown._createPopper (bootstrap.js:1896:40)
    at Dropdown.show (bootstrap.js:1813:12)
    at Dropdown.toggle (bootstrap.js:1800:51)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.js:2066:40)
    at HTMLDocument.handler (bootstrap.js:389:21)
```

I've tried using just the bundle that bootstrap provides with no luck i've tried everything i can think of but cannot seem to figure it out. Below is the drop-down menu.

```
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              <img class="rounded" src="<?php $_user->generateGravatar($_SESSION['userID'], 45); ?>">
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end position-absolute">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="#">Settings &nbsp; <i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i></a></li>
              <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="/auth/logout.php">Sign Out &nbsp; <i class="fa-solid fa-right-from-bracket"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

The order i call them in is popper.js first then bootstrap.js

Any help would be great. Like i mentioned earlier that it was working and i havent changed anything and now its not working.

I tried changing popper version to the specific udm bootstrap uses, ive tried using the bootstrap bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you are trying to include the bundled bootstrap to keep the name bootstrap.bundle.js fixed all problems after i renamed it from bootstrap.js